# Getting an error whenever the string is too long while passing it back to go from python script with cmd.Output()

Tags: python, go

I am parsing a pdf file with python and sending the text string back to golang server. When I run the code with smaller pdf file it works properly but with large pdf files it returns `exit status 1`

Here is the code i am using:

```
func parsePdf(path string) string {
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "pdf_parser.py", path)
    output, err := cmd.Output() //this line throws error
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    f, _ := os.Create("go-pdf-output.txt")
    _, err := f.WriteString(string(output))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err2)
    }
    return string(output)
}
```

This is the err I get from `cmd.Err`

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x18 pc=0xfc00e6]
```

This is my python script where I print the string after parsing:

```
import fitz
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]
doc = fitz.open(path)
list = []

for page in doc:
    text = page.get_text("text")
    list.append(text)

outputString= ' '.join(list)
print(outputString)
```

If I run the python script seperately it works perfectly. Error is thrown at this line `output, err := cmd.Output()` If the pdf file is small it works fine but if the pdf file is larger (ex: a book pdf) it fails.

I think the error is the size of bytes that the `cmd.Output()` can return. Is there any better way to transfer the data from python script to golang.

Comment: You don't appear to be calling [`cmd.Run`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Run)? (so I'm guessing your example code is incomplete?). Please include the stack trace that's output with the error (this should provide clues as to the cause of the issue). Note that you are outputting errors but then continuing regardless (and totally ignoring others) and my guess would be this is why you are getting the panic (probably caused by an earlier error - e.g. `os.Create` failing meaning `f` is nil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on my own. It's simple instead of printing the `outputString` directly, print a `json.dumps()`. I'll provide the whole code below:

**main.go** file

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

type ParseText struct {
    Text string `json:"text"`
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Running...")

    pdfPath := "./Y2V7 Full With SS-2.pdf"
    _, err := parsePdf(pdfPath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func parsePdf(path string) (string, error) {
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "pdf_parser.py", path)
    var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer

    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error when executing python: %s\n", stderr.Bytes())
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Error executing python: %w", err)
    }

    res := ParseText{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(stdout.Bytes(), &res)
    writeToFile("go-pdf.txt", res.Text)
    return res.Text, err
}
func writeToFile(fileName, text string) {
    f, err := os.Create(fileName)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    _, err2 := f.WriteString(text)

    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err2)
    }
}
```

**pdf-parser.py** file

```
import fitz
import sys
import json

URL = sys.argv[1]
doc = fitz.open(URL)
list = []

for page in doc:
    text = page.get_text("text")
    list.append(text)

outputString= ' '.join(list)
print(json.dumps({"text":outputString}))
```